# Is there a native way to re-handle a response to a prompt?

Tags: .net-core, botframework

Our chatbot (written in .NET core 3.1) has multiple prompts that offer choices in the form of buttons. After the users sends a turn through the chat (either by clicking a button or typing anything), we hide the buttons because clicking them simply sends the buttons text as a turn. Our prompt then picks up the user's response and compares it with the choice dictionary to produce a more backend friendly result for use in the dialog-step.

Users have given us feedback on how we handle them. One often requested feature is to scroll back up to a previous prompt and give a different response to a question. Here's an example:

"What kind of ultrasound do you want more information about?

- Location ultrasound
- Term ultrasound
- Structural ultrasound examination"

Users are often looking for only one of these, but the prompt itself sparks curiosity. They'll choose the option they were initially looking for and then want to see one of the other responses. Currently, our users will have to retype the phrase that triggered the Ultrasound Intent that routes them to the Ultrasound Dialog, where the prompt is triggered. Ideally they would scroll up to the prompt and just click on a different button, possible with an intermediate step where they click a "Choose a different option"-button on the prompt's question.

We've briefly looked into how we would implement this feature and were thinking of storing prompts' choice dictionaries across the conversation. Then we'd add a lot of custom logic to handle utterances, possibly through the use of special tags in the front-end. Or we'd have the intermediate step rewind the conversation to the prompt and handling their further actions from there.

Before we went ahead with any of this, we said to ourselves "Microsoft must have thought of this" but we were unable to find any documentation about the re-use of prompts.

Does the Bot Framework have a native way to allow users to reactivate a prompt from the front-end that has already been handled in the backend?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What channel/client are you using? Is it Web Chat?

Comment: We are currently using a Web Chat channel but are looking to change to Direct Line.

Comment: That doesn't quite make sense. Web Chat is a Direct Line client. Are you saying you want to switch from Web Chat to your own custom client?

Comment: We are using a Web Chat v3 client and are updating it to v4. In the Azure Web App Bot-service we use a Web Chat channel while in v4 we will be using a Direct Line channel.

Comment: There still seems to be some confusion here. Upgrading from Web Chat v3 to Web Chat v4 does not mean changing to Direct Line. Both versions of Web Chat use Direct Line as their channel. Direct Line is your channel in both cases. Web Chat may show up in the channels blade in Azure but it's technically not a channel. Web Chat v3 and Web Chat v4 are both Direct Line clients. I don't want to get too sidetracked from your question though. Since you're using Direct Line and Web Chat, the main point there is that you'll have some control over the client if you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no native way to re-handle a response to a prompt in the way you mean it. There are a few things you need to understand about the Bot Framework in order to [design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-design-principles) your bot correctly.

### What is a prompt?

A prompt is a type of [dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog) that can be thought of as the bot asking the user a question. It could be over in one turn if the user's answer is acceptable the first time, or it could take multiple turns if the bot doesn't get the information it needs right away. In the case of a choice prompt, the user's answer would only be acceptable if it can be recognized as one of the available choices. Since you mentioned choices, I will assume you're using a choice prompt.

A choice prompt can present its choices in five possible ways, called list styles. There are two ways it can present choices as buttons, two ways it can present choices as text, and one way it can present no choices at all. If you have a look at the [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.choices.liststyle) you can see a sixth option: "auto." This is the default, and it will pick the best option based on your choices and the channel's capabilities. In your case it must be presenting the choices as suggested actions.

### What are suggested actions?

[image: Suggested actions]

Suggested actions are buttons that disappear when the user clicks on one of them. Like all UI elements they are very channel-specific, and the Azure Bot Service will try to convert them into the appropriate format for the given channel. For example, in Facebook Messenger suggested actions will become "quick replies." Web Chat is part of the Bot Framework so no conversion needs to take place in your case.

You'll see in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-add-suggested-actions) that suggested actions serve the purpose of preventing your bot from having to worry about handling clicks on old cards:

> Unlike buttons that appear within rich cards (which remain visible and accessible to the user even after being tapped), buttons that appear within the suggested actions pane will disappear after the user makes a selection. This prevents the user from tapping stale buttons within a conversation and simplifies bot development (since you will not need to account for that scenario).

It sounds like your users want to be able to go back and click on buttons, so you'll want to use cards instead of suggested actions.

### What are cards?

There are currently about nine types of [cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-add-rich-cards) officially supported by the Bot Framework. [Adaptive Cards](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/) are great for more advanced scenarios, but since you just want a few buttons you can get away with the simplest option: hero cards.

[image: Hero card]

You may have noticed before that "hero card" is the other button option for list styles. So all you have to do is set up your prompt to use the hero card list style and your choices will be presented as a card instead of suggested actions.

This may be enough information for you to solve your issue, but I want to make sure you're on the right track. The reason I said "no" at the beginning is because you shouldn't try to rewind your dialog back to a specific prompt. That's not how dialogs or prompts are supposed to work. If you want the bot to be able to respond to those choices at any point in the dialog, you need to handle those choices as interruptions.

### What are interruptions?

[Interruptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-handle-user-interrupt) are when the bot responds to a user utterance or action in a way that doesn't follow the flow of the current dialog. You can see an example of interruptions in the [core bot sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Dialogs/CancelAndHelpDialog.cs). In that sample you can see the interruptions being handled only within the scope of a dialog, which lets you to decide when you want to allow interruptions. Alternatively, you can handle interruptions globally by putting that logic outside of any dialog.

You could set up your interruptions so that the bot will always be listening for the exact text in all your choices in all your choice prompts. The text would be a key phrase just like "help" or "cancel" in the sample. Note that if you go this route, the user could potentially access that functionality before the card gets sent by just typing in the key phrase. The alternative route is to make the buttons send [`postBack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-media-attachments#process-events-within-rich-cards) actions instead of the default `imBack` actions. This will send invisible messages that can't be simulated by the user typing, and they'll be easier for your bot to recognize as interruptions.

If you respond to the buttons as interruptions, it would make sense to not even have a prompt at all. When the dialog gets to the point where it would start the choice prompt, it could just send the card and end the dialog knowing that the bot will be able to respond to whatever the user picks. Note that this would mean that you wouldn't get to use all the choice recognition options that choice prompts provide, so the user wouldn't be able to do something like type the number 2.

Comment: Yes, it lines out all the options we have for implementing this feature.